# Indirect modification of overloaded element of Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model has no effect

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am getting this error when I try to remove an item from array. Other questions on SO says that this is because the variable is actually not an array. I also tried solutions. The code is as shown below.

```
    $temp = $tripsAndMatchStrengths['Responses']['userTrip'];

    foreach ($temp as $key => $trip)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            // code
        }
        else
        {                    
            // Remove this entry from array
            unset($temp[$key]);
        }
    }

    // Error is on this line
    $tripsAndMatchStrengths['Responses']['userTrip'] = $temp;
```

Comment: Why do not work on the array directly with [references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) ?

Comment: I tried `$temp = &$tripsAndMatchStrengths['Responses']['userTrip'];`. It gives same error on one more line `unset($temp[$key]);`.

Comment: `foreach ($tripsAndMatchStrengths['Responses']['userTrip'] as $key => &$trip)` I don't know if it will solve your problem, I've never saw this error before.

Comment: @Debflav I was using `foreach ($tripsAndMatchStrengths['Responses']['userTrip'] as $key => &$trip)` only at first. I could not solve this issue but used different approach in my code where I don't have to remove an object.